# Ошибка в функции

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function enter(button){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        document.getElementById(button).click();
    };
}
```

Вот код: https://jsfiddle.net/pvsr7c0u/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нажатие на Enter внутри формы вызывает клик первой сабмит кнопки.

```
function enter(event, button){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById(button).click();
    }
}

<input type="email" name="email" class="reg-forms large-forms" id="email"
  onkeydown="enter(event, 'email-btn')" autocomplete="email" placeholder="Email" />
...
<button type="button" class="reg-cancel-btn" id="email-cancel-btn" onclick="emailCancel()">Назад</button>
<button type="button" class="reg-btn" id="email-btn" onclick="emailNext()">Продолжить</button>
```

Comment: спасибо. Еще один вопрос, Вы знаете как  добавить в это регулярное выражение 0 или больше пробелов /^\p{L}{2,20}$/u;